# Angular 6, Materialize: initializing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, materialize

I am new to Angular and Materialize. I am trying to initialize a carousel within my Angular component.

Materialize mentions three ways:

```
M.AutoInit();
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
  });
```

or

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
  });
```

I have installed Materialize via node. I have both its CSS and JS as dependencies in my angular.json folder. The CSS styling works. I have tried these three methods within my `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook within my component. "M" is not recognized. I tried importing materialize:

```
import { materialize } from '../../../node_modules/materialize-css'
```

and

```
let m = materialize;
```

But this hasn't worked either.

I then installed jquery as a depedency and tried that method, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Share your code on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

just give this a try
import 'materialize-css';

Answer (score 2):

- import `OnInit` from `@angular/core` library
- `declare const M: any;` underneath imports
- fire the `M.AutoInit()` function in `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook

Example (where the component name is MediaComponent):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare const M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-media',
  templateUrl: './media.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./media.component.scss']
})
export class MediaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    M.AutoInit();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Materialize for Angular library. Asking how to use jQuery with Angular can get you a lot of downvotes.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize

Comment: I did not want to use jquery. I mentioned it only because after the first method of initializing didn't seem to work. I used the Materialize library for angular.

Answer (score 0):

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var M: any;

Comment: This is a so-called code-only answer and without an explanation of why it helps not appreciated. Also learning about formatting would be beneficial Take the [tour] as something of a good-luck-charm and read [answer].